# I have multiple blocks in design need to write the html code for that with the help divs

Tags: html, css

I am using this code to develop HTML code for the image below, but I am overlapping the divs, and stuck with code. I need to develop the solution with the help of divs in HTML.

```
<div style="width:80%; height: 80px;padding-right:110px;margin-right:40px">
    <div style="width:26%; float: left;float:left">
        <div class="pointer-blue-small1">Steps & User Requirements Definition</div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:15%; float: left;">
        <div class="pointer-blue-small1">High Level Design</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background:rgb(93,188,210);width:500px;height:110px;color:white;line-height:1.2;padding:10px;margin: 5px;">
        <div>
            <div style="background:rgb(143,63,123);width:390px; height:40px;color:white;text-align:center;line-height:1.2;float:left;padding-left:50px;margin-left:100px">A1901 Integrated Planning</div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
            <div class="pointer-purple-small" style="width:374px;height:40px;color:white;text-align:center;float:left;padding-left:50px;margin-left:100px;line-height:1.2;display:inline-block">A1102 Update Project Plan</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div  style="background:rgb(93,188,210);width:500px;height:60px;color:white;line-height:1.2;padding:10px;margin: 15px;display:inline-block;margin-left:6px">
        <div style="background:rgb(143,63,123);width:390px; height:40px;color:white;text-align:center;line-height:1.2;float:left;padding-left:50px;margin-left:100px">A1919 Change Request Control & Monitor and Report Risks and Issues</div>
    </div>
    <div style="background:rgb(93,188,210);width:500px;height:175px; color:white;line-height:1.2;padding:10px;margin: 5px;" ;display: inline-block;margin-left:35px">
        <div>
            <div style="background:rgb(143,63,123);width:390px; height:40px;color:white;text-align:center;line-height:1.2;float:left;padding-left:50px;margin-left:100px">A1105 Quality Assurance    </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
            <div  style="background:rgb(143,63,123);width:390px;height:40px;color:white;text-align:center;float:left;padding-left:50px;margin-left:100px;line-height:1.2;display:inline-block">A1922 StackHolder Management</div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
            <div class="pointer-purple-small" style="width:374px;height:40px;color:white;text-align:center;flo[![enter image description here][1]][1]at:left;padding-left:50px;margin-left:100px;line-height:1.2;display:inline-block">A1104 Update Quality Plan</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share the specific problem you are facing while developing that design. Any code issue or any specific alignment not achievable. Stackoverflow is to get help on your code where you are stuck instead of coding on your behalf.

Comment: You have some invalid HTML. Please run your code through an [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), fix the errors, and then update the code you have here with the fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.left-parent div {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
}

.row {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-parent {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.flex {
  display: flex
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row flex ">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="flex left-parent">
      <div class="border left-parent-child">

      </div>
      <div class="border left-parent-child">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border child">

    </div>
    <div class="border child">

    </div>
    <div class="border child">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right border">

  </div>

</div>
```